# skip a line aside a matrix

Tags: matrices, parskip

Well, This is what I tried to compile
If you compile it the sequence of number will be next to the matrix, but I want it to be in other line. Do you know how to do that space?
 Thank you so much in advance.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
\beta= \left[ \begin{array}{c}
   \beta_0      \\
   \beta_1      \\
   \vdots  \\
   \beta_k
   \end{array}
    \right],
\textbf{\epsilon}= \left[ \begin{array}{c}
            \epsilon_1      \\
            \epsilon_2      \\
            \vdots  \\
            \epsilon_n\\
           \end{array}
    \right]
    \]

    1234

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It's impossible to solve your problem from your screenshot, insert the code directly to the question text please, then we can more likely help you.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the whole code. By the way, \texbf{\epsilon} should not compile as the \epsilon command is n't in math mode.

Comment: What @Bernard comments is actually the answer. Load the package `bm` and change `\textbf{\epsilon}` to `\bm{\epsilon}` and everything will compile. You obviously don't read the log of the compilation at all since your code compiles with an error! It's no surprise that LaTeX produces a completely ridiculous output if there're compilation errors ;)

Answer (score 1):

The \textbf command won't make \epsilon boldfaced, as it is made for insertion of ordinary text inside math formulae. You should use the \bm command (from the bm package), which is made for math mode. Here is a correct code:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb, bm}
\begin{document}
\[
\beta= \left[ \begin{array}{c}
   \beta_0      \\
   \beta_1      \\
   \vdots  \\
   \beta_k
\end{array}
\right],
\quad
\bm{\epsilon} = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
        \epsilon_1      \\
        \epsilon_2      \\
        \vdots  \\
        \epsilon_n\\
       \end{array}
\right]
\]

1234

\end{document}
```

and [image: the result:]

By the way, I once asked how some can load fine antialiased images instead of a  miserable png. What's the trick, please?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm sorry that I can't help you though. I apreciate if you tell me when you find out how to do it ;)